# Drools Guided Decision Table throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, drools, grizzly, kie-workbench

When i create a guided decision table in kie workbench i get null pointer exception on execution of a stateless or statefull kie session. To be more specific i use drools 7 and i expose a simple rest service with java and grizzly. When i use simple drl files my rules are firing and executing correctly, but when i deploy with the decision table inside my jar i get NPE.

Java code:

```
 public CustomerDto executeStatelessPOC(final String param,
       final StatelessKieSession kSession ,final KieServices kServices) {
    //Myexample is just the entry fact
    InputDTO example = new InputDTO();
    example.setField1(param);       

    CustomerDto response = new CustomerDto();
    try {            

        KieCommands kieCommands = kServices.getCommands();
        List<Command> cmds = new ArrayList<Command>();
        cmds.add(kieCommands.newInsert(example));
        cmds.add(kieCommands.newInsert(response, "customerResponse"));           

        //Execute rules with facts provided before            
        ExecutionResults results = kSession.execute(kieCommands.newBatchExecution(cmds));
        //Get the response as part of the results
        response = (CustomerDto) results.getValue("customerResponse");
        return response;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception e: " + e.toString());
        System.out.println("Exception e: " + Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    }
    return response;
}
```

Source code of the guided decision table:

```
package gr.maven.test.testbuildinmaven;
```

//from row number: 1
rule "Row 1 TestDecisionTable"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        Input : InputDTO( field1 == "Test1" )
    then
        CustomerDto fact0 = new CustomerDto();
        fact0.setCustomerMessage( "yesss" );
        insertLogical( fact0 );
end

//from row number: 2
rule "Row 2 TestDecisionTable"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        Input : InputDTO( field1 == "Test2" )
    then
        CustomerDto fact0 = new CustomerDto();
        fact0.setCustomerMessage( "yes2" );
        insertLogical( fact0 );
end

//from row number: 3
rule "Row 3 TestDecisionTable"
    dialect "mvel"
    when
        Input : InputDTO( field1 == "Test3" )
    then
        CustomerDto fact0 = new CustomerDto();
        fact0.setCustomerMessage( "yesss" );
        insertLogical( fact0 );
end

Exception:

```
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: Unknown HK2 failure detected:
```

MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.reflection.ReflectionHelper.makeMe(ReflectionHelper.java:1129)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.createMe(ClazzCreator.java:274)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:368)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:653)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:381)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.guidedDecisionTableToPackageDescr(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:411)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl$ResourceToPkgDescrMapper.lambda$static$6(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:309)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildResource(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:187)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackageDescr(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:176)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.buildPackages(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:109)
        at org.drools.compiler.builder.impl.CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.build(CompositeKnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:99)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieProject.buildKnowledgePackages(AbstractKieProject.java:247)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.AbstractKieModule.createKieBase(AbstractKieModule.java:210)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.createKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:389)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:357)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newStatelessKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:550)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newStatelessKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:460)
        at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.newStatelessKieSession(KieContainerImpl.java:455)
        at com.mycompany.grizzlypoc.rest.services.StatelessService.(StatelessService.java:37)
        ... 37 more
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: create on com.mycompany.grizzlypoc.rest.services.StatelessService
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:395)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.findOrCreate(RequestScope.java:162)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:711)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:653)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:169)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:92)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:61)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:288)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1110)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:381)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:219)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 2):

Problem is solved using this dependency in my POM xml.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-workbench-models-guided-dtable</artifactId>
        <version>7.7.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had confused which `POM.xml` file should be changed (i.e. rule side or application side).

Today I tried and got that answer! it necessary with **application side**.

My build.gradle is below:

---

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        drools_version = '7.7.0.Final'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.drools:drools-workbench-models-guided-dtable:$drools_version"
    compile "org.kie:kie-api:$drools_version"
}
```

---

It worked fine my kotlin project.